# How to prevent old Activity state data restoration when an Application is restarted?

Tags: android, android-activity, rotation, orientation, state

When rotation, i.e, a change in orientation occurs, an Activity is destroyed and then created again, resetting activity state data. This is remedied by overriding onSaveInstance and saving the state data to its Bundle parameter.

But when the Back key is pressed, signaling the user's intent to really exit the Application, there seems to be no mechanism to get rid of or update that state Bundle since onSaveInstance does not get called. If the user restarts the app again, before the system has killed the old instance of the Application, the old state Bundle gets restored again, rather than starting out fresh and re-creating the Activity. Now after the app is killed by the system, the problem goes away. But I don't think it's possible to force the app to be killed by overriding onBackPressed, for instance.

So my question is, how to guaranty the Activity be reinitialized with a new state, next time the app is run? Any advice would be greatly appreciated - thanx!

Comment: What’s really happening is static activity variables values persist when an app that previously exited gets restarted before it gets killed by the system. It really doesn’t have anything to do with the saveInstanceState Bundle, or events that occur during rotation.

Comment: Now that I have put android:configChanges="orientation" in the Activity definition in manifest.xml, the state of my activity data gets preserved when there is an orientation/rotation change. The only thing that gets called is onConfigurationChange(), but there is no need to handle it. Without that statement, the activity acts like it is exiting and restarting again and onSaveInstanceState(), onPause(), onStop(), onDestroy(), as well as onCreate(), onRestoreInstanceState() and onResume() all get called.

Answer (score 3):

This is depends on what manner do you want to preserve your information.

1.If you want to preserve that data while only orientation change.
   Then best way you can use `onSaveInstanceState(...)` and `onRestoreInstanceState(...)`

You can handle configuration change inside manifest in activity decalaration.

`android:ConfigChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` and you can call the `onConfigurationChanged (Configuration newConfig)`

2.If you want the preserve that data while restarting app or till clear cache or uninstall then you can use SharedPreferences.

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: Thanks very much! It turns out I had placed android:ConfigChanges="orientation" in the application section, instead of in the activity declaration, where it should be in the manifest. So onConfigurationChanged never gets called, and rotation causes the app to act like it has exited and restarted. Also, this is the only case in which onSaveInstanceState and then onRestoreInstanceState get called. With the inclusion of the ConfigChanges attribute in the Activity definition, only onConfigurationChange gets called, solving the problem of losing the activity's state.

Answer (score 0):

Back key calls the finish function for the current Activity but home key doesn't it keeps the activity running in its background.
By answering your question if you press back button and you have override the saved instance state function and starts the activity again then it will not restore the previous activity instance and if you press the home button the the activity will not create as the previous activity will come into foreground which goes to background as by pressing home button

Comment: Thank you for your comments, but in my tests, onSaveInstanceState does not seem to get called when finish() is called, nor does overriding onStop or onDestroy seem to help.

Comment: The savedInstanceState method is called when we want the activity to restart again by storing its instance but if we called the finish function this means we dont want to save its instance and therefore it will not call the onSaveInstance state and it will call the onstop and ondestroy function

Answer (score 0):

I think for this you have to clear your data when the activity is getting destroyed. You can create a function to initialize your app data and call this function from the onDestroy().

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how do you access the Activity state bundle in this case? onDestroy doesn't pass it like onSaveInstanceState does.

Answer (score 0):

Rotation re-creates your activity and you can save your activities state by onSaveInstanceState and restoreInstanceState methods. But you want something different. When you press back button, activity is going to be finished and next launch of your activity will be different then previous instance, so you can't retrieve saved instance state. If you want to store state for activity for all its instances, you may sttore your activities data to shared preferences.

Comment: Thanks! Using SharedPreferences looks promising when used with onCreate to read and onBackPressed to write state data. Problem is, no matter whether it's a change in orientation or an exit, onPause, onStop and onDestroy get called. Overriding onBackPressed seems the only way to distinguish a user exit event and update a boolean to indicate such has occurred.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I solved preserving my activity state during rotation. See my other comment about android:ConfigChanges="orientation" in the activity definition in the manifest. What I also discovered is that a static boolean I was setting  retained its value on restarting because the activity hasn't been destroyed after exiting. But it had nothing to do with saving or restoring state values with onSaveInstanceState(...) and onRestoreInstanceState(...) which now does not get called during rotation.